# Trouble making a new column using case_when in Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I'm try to make a new column in my data frame which will contain only the receivers we set up in one are of study. I've checked other pages on here but I still get the same error:

<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with `mutate()` input `ER`.
x Case 1 (`Receiver %in% c("1326", "1315", "1314", "1321", "1404", "1318", "1325", "1313...`) must be a two-sided formula, not a logical vector.
i Input `ER` is `case_when(...)`.
Backtrace:
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

I've tried:

```
ev<-ev %>% 
  select(Receiver) %>% 
  mutate(ER=case_when(c(Receiver=="1315"|
                         Receiver=="1314"|
                         Receiver=="1321"|
                        Receiver=="1404"|
                        Receiver=="1318"|
                        Receiver=="1325"|
                        Receiver=="1313"|
                        Receiver=="1323"|
                        Receiver=="1324"|
                        Receiver=="1320"|
                        Receiver=="1319"|
                        Receiver=="1317")))
```

And:

```
ev<-ev %>%   
  mutate(ER=case_when(Receiver %in% c("1326", "1315", "1314", "1321", "1404", "1318", "1325", "1313", "1323", "1324", "1320", "1319", "1317")))
```

Any help showing me where I've gone wrong is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have two studies, `study_A` and `study_B`. Then you need to add replacement values e.g. for only two of your given strings:

```
ev <- ev %>%
   mutate(ER = case_when(Receiver == "1326" ~ "study_A", 
                         Receiver == "1315" ~ "study_B"))
```

Comment: Ah I see what I'm doing wrong then. Thank you.
In that case would it be better just to use filter() to extract all the receivers I want into a new date frame? There's nothing in the data frame to distinguish the receivers from different sites.

Comment: Depends on how many individual data frames you want to generate. I assume one for each of your studies, right? Then of course it's easier to simply use filter() to store the data related to the specific receivers.